# How to Use DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy in java using Java Driver (2.0.2,3.1) and cassandra 3.7

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cql, nosuchmethoderror

I have configured cassandra cluster with 2 datacenters, and 3 nodes each. i wanted to use DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy to specify the local datacenter. i tried using both Datastax java driver 2.0.2 and 3.1. but with 2.0.2 there no compile time error rather in run-time i am getting NoSuchMethodError and 3.1 giving me the DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy() constructor is not visible.

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Java Cassandra Driver 3.1 you now use a builder to create your DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy

```
DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy dcAwareRoundRobinPolicy = DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
    .withLocalDc("my-dc")
    .withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(1)
    .build();
```

I would also suggest using TokenAware as well so when you are building your cluster add

```
Cluster.Builder()
    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(dcAwareRoundRobinPolicy))
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. It worked nicely.but now i am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.driver.core.Message error the corresponding class is exists in the classpath. can you please let me know any idea?

Comment: What does your maven or gradle file look like for importing the Java driver?

Comment: I am not using maven. i have imported all jars into WEB-INF/lib folder and added to buildpath in eclipse.

Comment: Send like you may have mixed versions in there make sure it's only the 3.1 driver jars

Comment: Is there anything else you want added to the answer before you accept it?

Comment: Actually i faced issue with jars like netty. i was using different versions of jars.i have changed the versions, its worked.i accepted your answer already.

Comment: To  accept the answer you can hit the checkmark on the left of the answer so it turns green.